# RegEx: End of rule detected too late if not using ^ anchor

Tags: javascript, regex

I use a `JavaScript` `RegEx` rule to match `url` strings and convert them automatically to a link element when typing.

This was my `RegEx` rule:

```
/^(((http(s)?|(ftp(s)?)):\/\/)(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.\/-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})+(\:[0-9]{5})?|(mailto:){1}([\w\.]+)\@{1}[\w]+\.[\w]{2,})\s$/gm;
```

At the end of the rule I detect space with `\s` in combination with the `$` anchor. So when the user types `https://www.google.com` and hits a space at the end to continue typing, the `url` converts to an link element.

I had to remove the first anchor `^` at the beginning of the rule, to ignore strings typed in before my url such as e.g. `hello world https://www.google.com`:

```
/(((http(s)?|(ftp(s)?)):\/\/)(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.\/-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})+(\:[0-9]{5})?|(mailto:){1}([\w\.]+)\@{1}[\w]+\.[\w]{2,})\s$/gm;
```

Since I removed the first anchor, which marks the start of the `RegEx`, I have hit three times `space` at the end to match the rule.

E.g. with anchor `^`:
(typing) `https://www.google.com` + hit space at the end -> the rule matches. Hit another space will insert a space and I can continue writing.

E.g. without anchor `^`:
(typing) `https://www.google.com` + hit space at the end -> the rule matches. Hit another space -> nothing happens. Hit space third time will insert a space and I can continue writing. So there is an additional space.

I tried to put in the `\s$` at the end of each rule, but didn't help:

```
/(((http(s)?|(ftp(s)?)):\/\/)(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.\/-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})+(\:[0-9]{5})?)\s$|((mailto:){1}([\w\.]+)\@{1}[\w]+\.[\w]{2,})\s$/gm
```

Any ideas? Hope the description of the issue is understandable.

Comment: Your alternatives before `\s$` are grouped that is why it makes no sense adding `\s$`  for each alternative. Your regex works as is, matching the URL at the end of the line when followed with space.  Please provide a demo snippet to repro the issue.

Comment: addition to @Wiktor's comment : using `$` inside multiline regex means "end of line".

Comment: also note that if you don't want to scratch your head for too long, you could take a look at the [twitter-text library](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js)
(especially [this part](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/js/src/extractUrlsWithIndices.js))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using the `tiptap` editor: https://tiptap.scrumpy.io/, which is an editor for `Vue`. It's not that easy to provide an working example but I will try.

@RokoC.Buljan Since I'm using the `tiptap` I have the opportunity to provide some `input` and `paste` rules, but for this I have to use `RegEx`...